# Twitter Single Account Logon iPhone

Tags: iphone, twitter, authentication, account

Hello is there a way to enable auto login for twitter using oAuth authentication. There have been similiar posts of how I could store username and password together with access token so the app logs into one account on Twitter.

Any specific advise of how i could implement it using would be very helpful. Should I consider NSUser defaults to store username and password etc

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Just check cookies in your code and make them like:

```
Clear_cookies=NO;
```

Please provide your source code, so that I can tell you in detail.

Comment: How can i send you my project?

Comment: @user put the relevant portions of your code into your question within markdown code regions.

Comment: Plz Send it to iphonedev2006@gmail.com.I will reponse as soon as possible.